# How do I handle argument options?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making slash commands with Discord.js and wrote my own handler. I am facing an issue with handling the arguments so it will throw an error when the type of slash command is a sub command, or a sub command group. This does not affect slash commands that are not a sub command.

If the type of command is a **`SUB_COMMAND`**, it will return an array of objects which contain the `value` key. This will however only show when options have been defined in the `options` array so `value` will be empty when there is nothing (String, number etc.) provided.

What a Sub Command returns with arguments passed:

`[ { name: 'eightball', type: 'SUB_COMMAND', options: [ { value: "some text" }  ] } ]`

What a Sub command returns with no arguments passed:

`[ { name: 'eightball', type: 'SUB_COMMAND' } ]`

If it is not a sub command:

`[ { name: 'reason', type: 'STRING', value: 'hello' } ]`
or
an empty array.

Code:

```js
interaction.options.data.reduce((args, arg) => {
  if (arg.type === "SUB_COMMAND") {
    if (arg.options.length > 1) {
       args[arg.name] = arg.options.map(option => option.value);
    } else if (arg.options.length < 1 && arg.options[0].value) {
       args[arg.name] = arg.options[0].value;
    } else {
       args[arg.name].value = null;
    }
  } else {
    args[arg.name] = arg.value;
  }

  return args;
}, {})
```

Comment: Resolved issue.

Comment: If you resolved it, please post it how you did it as an answer for your own question. You can also mark your own answer as correct.